# How to display a login menu in UNIX AIX?

Tags: unix, ssh, authentication, aix

I'm a UNIX AIX administrator and as per the security design, each user should have specific privileges and some user have "sftp" only they don't have ssh.

When user password expires, I have to reset the password for the user by myself ( because he don't have access as ssh to execute commands ) so I'm thinking if there is some way I can enable SSH for users but show them only specific tasks like below scenario :

---

User: xxxxxx
password : *******

1- Reset User.
2- Change Password.

Choose Option :

---

Comment: Too long to repost here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-sshsecurity/index.html

Comment: Also Korn scripting: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-kornshellscripting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you'll need to write a little script for the users. AIX uses Korn shell, so [you can write little scripts for the user](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-kornshellscripting/) based on whatever parameters you like.

[Info for modifying the SSH permissions for the individual users.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-sshsecurity/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, I read all links but I couldn't find where I should add the script to be executed on startup ( after login).  some references say I should add it to ~/user/bashrc but I couldn't find this folder!
do you have any Idea where I can add the script in UNIX AIX

Comment: You can execute it at login with ssh, or try to put it in the user's `.profile` file. Make sure the script is in the right folder and has the right permissions though.